# Show max value of 10 rows in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have one report in which I want to show 10 employees data which have max salary. I want to do this by SSRS please help me. Please do it by SSRS not by SSMS.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you have a Dataset with one row per employee which is sorted by salary, descending.

You can apply a `TOP N` filter to the table and set this to 10; this should return only the first ten rows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156270(v=sql.100).aspx

You could also set the `Hidden` attribute for the detail row in the table based on an expression that uses the RowNumber() function, e.g.

`=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) <= 10, False, True)` which should work, too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just adding my 5 cents (and a picture) here: I had an issue that the filter should be applied only for integers. So I applied a value conversion as shown below.
[image: configuration of top n filter]

Answer (score 2):

For top 10 records from a dataset.

1: Go to the Row Group properties and add a filter on for TOP N .

```
Expression =Sum(Fields!ActualCost.Value)
```

2 . Sorting on `"=Sum(Fields!ActualCost.Value)"` Field Name in Descending order.