# Tablix Row Limit

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

How do you limit the number of rows inside a tablix?

Comment: http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html

Comment: There isn't enough information to accurately answer this, The answer could be a multitude of different things. Screen Shots and more description would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225792/show-max-value-of-10-rows-in-ssrs